# How to handle async when making mongoose query in each array element in express?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, async-await

On the following post method, I'm having some issues due to moongose async. `res.send(suggestions)` is executed first then `Expense.findOne.exec`

```
app.post('/suggestions', async function(req, res) {
    const suggestions = await req.body.map((description) => {
        Expense.findOne({ description: new RegExp(description, 'i') }).exec((err, result) => {
            if (result) {
                console.log(result.newDescription);
                return {
                    description,
                    newDescription: result.newDescription,
                    category: result.category,
                    subcategory: result.subcategory
                };
            }
        });
    });

    res.send(suggestions);
});
```

The result is a array of null values. How can I executed a query for each item, then execute `res.send(suggestion)`?

Answer (score 0):

Found solution with the following code:

```
app.post('/suggestions', async function(req, res) {
    try {
        if (req.body.length > 0) {
            const suggestions = req.body.map((description) =>
                Expense.findOne({ description: new RegExp(description, 'i') })
            );

            const results = await Promise.all(suggestions);
            return res.send(results);
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('error', e);
    }
});
```